# Can't find PhoneAuthProvider class using Firebase with Xamarin in Xamarin.Firebase.Auth

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android, firebase-authentication

I'm am using Xamarin.Firebase.Auth https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.Auth/ latest version

I want to use Firebase Phone Authentication and require the PhoneAuthProvider ** class but I can't seem to find it under Firebase.Auth.
Just to mention only **PhoneAuthProvider** class is missing whereas I can see the **TwitterAuthProvider** **EmailAuthProvider** etc.

What option do I have, I require phone authentication with Firebase on Xamarin
Thanks

Comment: I found the same problem as you did, may be you can submit an issue to [GooglePlayServicesComponents](https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues) on github.